# Image processing : Mean of line sample

Tags: c++, opencv, mean

I would like to know the `mean` of each columns on my image source. The goal is when the first columns which have a average of 0 (all my pixels are black) a boolean is switch for leave a `while`.

I do not know if I use a `vector` , a `Mat` function , `Line` or another way.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You can compute the *mean* (and *sum*, *min*, *max*) of each *column* (or *row*) in a matrix using [reduce](http://docs.opencv.org/2.4/modules/core/doc/operations_on_arrays.html#reduce)

This is a small example that shows how to compute the mean of each column and each row.

```
#include <opencv2/opencv.hpp>
using namespace cv;

int main()
{
    // Create a random 1 channel matrix
    Mat1b img(10,20);
    randu(img, Scalar(0), Scalar(10));

    // Compute the mean of each column
    Mat1f colMean;
    reduce(img, colMean, 0, CV_REDUCE_AVG, CV_32F);

    // colMean is a 1x20 matrix (row matrix)

    // Compute the mean of each row
    Mat1f rowMean;
    reduce(img, rowMean, 1, CV_REDUCE_AVG, CV_32F);

    // rowMean is a 10x1 matrix (column matrix)

    return 0;
}
```

Note that to check if values in a column (row) are all zero, you can also use `CV_REDUCE_SUM` or `CV_REDUCE_MAX`, i.e. you can sum all pixels or take only the maximum value. In every case, when a column (row) contains only zero values, the result will be zero.

Comment: Amazing ! Thank you very much.